# Membership comparsion in python

Tags: python

I am not sure whether i am doing it correctly but please consider the below code. a and b values are same (i.e "John") but when doing a membership test (i.e a in b) then it says false. But when checking the value equality then it shows True but somehow membership test is saying false even though the values are same.

```
>>> import redis
>>> r.mset(first="John", second="Stanley", third="Junior")
>>> a = r.mget(["first"])
>>> a
['John']
>>> b = r.mget(["first"])
>>> b
['John']
>>> a in b
False
>>> a == b
True
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check below console result.

```
>>> ['John'] in ['John'] # list in list
False
>>> ['John'] in [['John']] # list in double list
True
>>> 'John' in ['John'] # Probably this is what you want.
True
>>> ['John'] == ['John']
True
>>> 'John' == ['John'] # 'John' is an element in List ['John'] but not same.
False
```

And redis support 'exsits' keyword.

```
>>> r.exists('John')
True
>>> r.exists('foo')
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Because a and b are both lists, list b doesn't contain list a, but they are equal.

Comment: When i do a type(a) and type(b) then it says both are lists. Am i missing something here ?

Comment: Yes, 'a' should be [['John']] and 'b' should be ['John'], in that case 'a' contain element ['John'] which is equal to 'b', and 'b in a' returns True.

Answer (score 0):

List `b` (which is `['John']`) does not contain the list `['John']`. It contains the string `'John'`.

Comment: That is not in dispute.

Comment: Being equal to a thing is different from containing a thing.